# Update (range of) cells in worksheets by calling a row based vba-function

Tags: arrays, range, valueerror

I would like to parse strings using a row-based VBA-function. The strings are imported from a CSV-file, where the field-data is encapsulated between two "-characters. The strings are stored in column [A] of worksheet "SO".

Function "Parse_Str" parses the string, stores the data into an one-dimensional array and provides a boolean result stored in column [B]. It has two arguments:
1. the to be parsed string
2. the address of the first cell where the range should be stored in

```
[A]                                [B]
"001","Name 1","Descripton 1"      =Parse_Str(A2; adres(rij(C2); kolom(C2)))
"002","Name 2","Descripton 2"      =Parse_Str(A3; adres(rij(C3); kolom(C3)))
"003","Name 3","Descripton 3"      =Parse_Str(A4; adres(rij(C4); kolom(C4)))
"004","Name 4","Desc 4","Rem 4"    =Parse_Str(A5; adres(rij(C5); kolom(C5)))
```

During function execution, the array is saved to a range started at C2, C3, C4 etc.  Desired output:

```
[B]    [C]    [D]       [E]                [F]
TRUE   001    Name 1    Description 1
TRUE   002    Name 2    Description 2
TRUE   003    Name 3    Description 3 
TRUE   004    Name 4    Desc 4             Rem 4
```

### Source code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim s_SRCE As String, s_DEST As String
Dim b As Boolean
Dim r As Range

    'Clear destination fields
    Worksheets("SO").Range("C2", "F5").Value = ""

    For i = 2 To 5
        Set r = Worksheets("SO").Range("A" & i)

        s_SRCE = r.Value
        s_DEST = Worksheets("SO").Range("C" & i).Address

        'Parse string and fill destination fields
        b = Parse_Str(s_SRCE, s_DEST)
    Next i

End Sub

Function Parse_Str(s_TRN As String, s_ADR As String) As Boolean

Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, p As Integer, q As Integer
Dim r As Range
Dim a() As String

    'Replace combinations of comma and double qoutes by '|'
    s_TRN = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(s_TRN & ",", "0000000000", ""), """,""", "|"), ",""", "|"), """,", "|"), """", "")

    'Get number of fields
    n = Len(s_TRN) - Len(Replace(s_TRN, "|", ""))

    ReDim a(1 To n)

    'Parse string to array
    p = 1
    For i = 1 To n
        q = InStr(p, s_TRN, "|")
        a(i) = Mid(s_TRN, p, q - p)
        p = q + 1
    Next i

    Set r = Worksheets("SO").Range(s_ADR)
    Set r = r.Resize(1, n)
    r.Value = a

    Parse_Str = Worksheets("SO").Range(s_ADR).Value <> ""

End Function
```

**Running sub "Test" provides the desired output in sheet "SO".**
However, calling function "Parse_Str" from sheet "SO" it doesn't and results in **#VALUE**-errors in column [B].

Comment: How can we tell without seeing the code?

Comment: Source code added

Comment: Reformatting text

Comment: (1) A function called from a sheet can only return a value to the cell it's in so you can't call your function this way as it stands (btw its return value is a boolean). (2) Why don't you just text to columns? Or Split.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I did do text to columns. The example is simple. In real I have to parse strings, consisting dynamically of 19 to 26 data fields. Because in VBA it is possible to call a function updating the columns, I saw it as a challenge to do so in EXCEL.    My policy is trying, as much as possilbe, to replace (storage and/or performance consuming) excel-functionality by VBA-logic. _Do you agree?_

Comment: Not sure I do, I think it's probably better to use built-in functionality where possible. You can manipulate TTC in VBA.